# No loading source code for the all jobs azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

How to avoid loading source code for the jobs azure DevOps pipeline every time. How can I make a download once source code, and then use it in all jobs? I set up a parallel launch of my jobs in the pipeline and now I have to spend time loading code every time. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below answer? If you use Microsoft-hosted agents. this cannot be done. However, there is a way to achieve this in self-hosted agent.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I make a download once source code, and then use it in all jobs

If you use Microsoft-hosted agents. It cannot be done. Because each job in your pipeline will get a fresh virtual Machine when you run your pipeline, The virtual machine is discarded after one use. So the source code downloaded in one job is not available for another job.

However it is possible in self-hosted agent. You can try creating a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) and run your pipeline on this self-hosted agent. See below example:

I have below pipeline for testing on my self-hosted agent.

```
pool: Default #run pipeline on self-hosted agent
stages: 
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - powershell: |
        echo "job1"> job1.txt
        ls
  - job: 
    dependsOn: A
    steps:
    - checkout: none
    - powershell: |
         echo "job2"> job2.txt
         ls
```

See output in the second powershell task: The source code is only loaded for once in the first job. And the following jobs can use the it too.

[image]

If you want to skip downloading the source code for your whole pipeline. You can check below steps.

Click the **3dots** on your yaml pipeline edit page--> Select **Triggers**-->Go the **Yaml** tab-->go to **Get sources** section--> Check **Don't sync sources**. See below screenshot.

[image]

[image]

But if you want to load the source code in some of the jobs. You can then add a script task to run the `git clone` commands to clone the source in this job (ie. `git clone https://$(System.Accesstoken)@dev.azure.com/org/pro/_git/rep` )

If you want to skip downloading source code for some of your jobs. You can also use [checkout step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#checkout) (ie. `checkout: none`).

```
stages: 
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: 
    steps:
    - checkout: none  #skip loading source in this job
  
  - job: 
    steps:
    - checkout: self  #loading source in this job
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as [job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/key-pipelines-concepts?view=azure-devops#job)

> A stage contains one or more jobs. Each job runs on an agent. A job represents an execution boundary of a set of steps. All of the steps run together on the same agent. For example, you might build two configurations - x86 and x64. In this case, you have one build stage and two jobs.

So technically they run on separate machines:

[image]

Question is if you need source code on all those jobs. If not you can disable downloading source code by adding step `checkout: none`.